# Changing the field digit style using java script in acrobat PDF forms

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-form

Using java script of PDF forms, how to change the digits style (from English to Arabic numbers) of a script-added-field?

Comment: One option would be changing the textFont of the field.

Comment: I've managed to work around that by creating a digit mapping function for each field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

digit mapping function for each field:

```
var eng_digits = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","."]
var arb_digits = ["٠","١","٢","٣","٤","٥","٦","٧","٨","٩",","]
function change_digits(num,form){
    var string = "" + num
    var digits = string.split("")
    for (i=0; i<digits.length; i++){
        if(form == "arb"){
            digits[i] = arb_digits[eng_digits.indexOf(digits[i])];
        }else if (form == "eng"){
            digits[i] = eng_digits[arb_digits.indexOf(digits[i])];
        }
    }
    return digits.join("");
}

this.getField("myField").value = change_digits(this.getField("myField").value, "arb")
```